# How can i find the difference between two dataframes on key column and remove the unique records from both dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to compare the two daraframes based on key(branch) and also planning to remove the records based on key which are not matching from the both datasets.

Comment: Where is your code? What did you try so far? Your question seems to be about returning the intersection of two Dataframes. If so, then at least give a starting point from your side. The way your question is formatted at the moment one could not even directly import `df1` and `df2` into some notebook / ipython to quickly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @daniel451 i am able get the record which are not matching from the both dataframes using below command          
        diff_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['branch'], how='outer')    , can you please tell me how i can delete the record which are  not matching  from both dataframes separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an inner merge

`df1.merge(df2, on='branch', how='inner')`